# Can we bound $\|a+b\|$ if $\|ae-a\|$ and $\|be\|$ are small, in a $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: inequality, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra with $a,b,e\in A$ such that $e\geq0$ and $\|e\|\leq1$. If $\|ae-a\|\leq\varepsilon$ and $\|be\|\leq\varepsilon$, then is $\|a+b\|\leq\max\{\|a\|,\|b\|\}+2\varepsilon$?

The reason I believe this is true, is because this holds for all homomorphisms $h$ on $A$. We get $|h(a-ae)|\leq\varepsilon$, $|h(be)|\leq\varepsilon$ and $0\leq h(e)\leq1$. This gives
\begin{align}
|h(a+b)|
&=|h(a-ae)+h(ae)+h(b-be)+h(be)|
\\&\leq|h(e)h(a)+(1-h(e))h(b)|+|h(a-ae)|+|h(be)|
\\&\leq\max\{|h(a)|,|h(b)|\}+2\varepsilon.
\end{align}
If I remember correctly, only in abelian $C^*$-algebras we have the equality $\|a\|=\sup h(a)$ where $h$ is any homomorphism. This means that we have solved the question for abelian $C^*$-algebras, but not for others.

I tried to solve this with only norm inequalities, but I only found one in the wrong direction:
\begin{align}
\|a+b\|
&\geq\|a+b\|\|e\|
\\&\geq\|ae+be\|
\\&\geq\|a\|-\|ae-a\|-\|be\|
\\&\geq\|a\|-2\varepsilon.
\end{align}
I could not even find an inequality of the form $\|a+b\|\geq\|b\|-\phi(\varepsilon)$ where $\phi(\varepsilon)\to0$ as $\varepsilon\to0$.

Comment: What does $e\geq 0$ mean here?

Comment: It means $e$ is a positive element. So $e$ is hermitian ($e=e^*$) and $\sigma(e)\subseteq[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true. Let $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, and 
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \ b=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ e=\begin{bmatrix} 1-\varepsilon&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} . 
$$
Then
$$
ae-a=\begin{bmatrix} -\varepsilon&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
so $\|ae-a\|=\varepsilon$. Also $be=0$, so $\|be\|<\varepsilon$. And 
$$
a+b=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
so 
$$
\|a\|=1,\ \|b\|=1,\ \ \|a+b\|=\sqrt2. 
$$

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Do you think we can reduce it to $\|a+b\|\leq\sqrt{\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2}+2\varepsilon$? I have a feeling this might be possible with Gelfand-Naimark-Segal construction.

Comment: I made a separate thread for this follow up question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053615/is-ab-leq-sqrt-a-2-b-22-varepsilon-when-ae-a-leq-varepsilo